# How to avoid BusinessLogic duplication in Integration Tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have one web service method that returns product changes history, it signature looks like this:

```
List<MyProduct> GetProductHistory(int iProductId);
```

I would like to create an INTEGRATION test for this method. For that I need to create some data in DB. Here I can create a function that writes some 'hard-coded' records in DB that will simulate product changes history.

I also need to test other function (int GetProductAverageValue(int iProductId)) which should do some data processing using product history information. In order to test this function I need to have few sets of records (few different history types). And here I have few choices:

1. Create a few different hard-coded sets of data (each per test case) (there are a lot of data there, so these sets are a little bit scary);
2. Create some functionality inside of my integration tests that will create required history for product...

1st option is scary huge, 2nd - leads to duplication of business logic on the Integration Tests layer...

Please advise. Any thoughts are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my 2nd question today... in which I found solution myself when completed question writing.

To create 'good set of product changes history' I need to use service methods that actually change products. Easy and quick :)

P.S. anyway, any comments and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> there are a lot of data there, so these sets are a little bit scary

I don't quite understand what the difficulty is here. Perhaps you can clarify why this is scary?

When the number of test cases necessary to test some code completely is too large (which is *always* the case for real programs), use [equivalence partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) to select a smaller number of test cases that nevertheless thoroughly test the code.

You have specifically said this is for integration testing. Do you already have thorough unit tests? If not, create those first. Then the integration tests no longer need to test business logic; they only need to test that the components have been glued together correctly. That should not require a huge number of test cases. If it does, consider redesigning your code to introduce an intermediate level of assembly (a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)) that you can test without the database.

Comment: Under "integration test" I mean test that do testing of whole service, not only of components linked to each other. For example, it should 'login', 'CreateProduct', 'check DB if product really exists'. Or another case: 'Login', 'DeleteProduct', 'check DB if product was really deleted. Probably better name would be functional automated tests?